# Unable to start the mysql in aws instance ec2 WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I thought of securing my wordpress i have changes the file permission system.
now my mysql server is not starting and i am getting wordpress database connection error

mysqld.log

```
2020-08-24T16:34:16.593492Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2020-08-24T16:34:16.596808Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1773
2020-08-24T16:34:16.842762Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-08-24T16:34:16.842772Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-08-24T16:34:16.842787Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-08-24T16:34:16.842800Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2020-08-24T16:34:16.842814Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

Comment: ibdata1  should be un the data directory specified in my.cnf but mysql can't find it, so check if everything is in order

Comment: Changed which file permissions? What did you change to?

Comment: @jordanm I don't remember

Comment: @ndk there is no ibdata1 file in data directory